# kubectl proxy within ubuntu in WSL windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I´m running windows 10 with WSL1 and ubuntu as distrib.
My windows version is Version 1903 (Build 18362.418)

I´m trying to connect to kubernetes using kubectl proxy within ubuntu WSL. I get a connection refused when trying to connect to the dashboard with my browser.

[image]

I have checked in windows with netstat -a to see active connections.

[image]

If i run kubectl within the windows terminal i have no problem to connect to kubernetes, so the problem is only happening when i try to connect with ubuntu WSL1.

I have also tried to run the following command

```
kubectl proxy --address='0.0.0.0' --port=8001 --accept-hosts='.*'
```

... but the connection is refused although i see that windows is listening to the port. Changing port to another port didn´t fix the proble. Disabling the firewall didnt´fix the problem as well.

Any idea ?

Comment: Apart from being unable to run 'kubectl proxy' within WSL, are you able to safely talk to your cluster: (`kubectl get svc -n kube-system`, `kubectl cluster-info`)?

Comment: @OhHiMark your comment was very relevant. The $HOME/.kube was not created.
That fixed the problem:
gcloud container clusters get-credentials default --region=europe-west1-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to do would be to check if you able to safely talk to your cluster: (`kubectl get svc -n kube-system`, `kubectl cluster-info`)

If not check if `$HOME/.kube` folder was created. If not, run:
`gcloud container clusters get-credentials default --region=<your_region>`

Answer (score 0):

WSL has a virtual ip, so 127.0.0.1 (localhost) from windows points at your windows host (not WSL).

I wrote this `run-proxy.sh` script, hopefully it helps others

```
#!/bin/bash

# Find the WSL2 IP Address
wsl_ip=$(ip addr show eth0 | grep 'inet\b' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1)

if [ -z "$wsl_ip" ]; then
    echo "Failed to find the WSL2 IP address."
    exit 1
fi

echo "WSL2 IP Address: $wsl_ip"

# Set the desired port for kubectl proxy
proxy_port=8001

echo "Starting kubectl proxy on http://$wsl_ip:$proxy_port"
echo "dashboard: http://$wsl_ip:$proxy_port/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/"
kubectl proxy --address="$wsl_ip" --port=$proxy_port --accept-hosts='.*'

# Note: You can access Kubernetes API from Windows using http://$wsl_ip:$proxy_port
```